# Unable to plot the graph for ff=2 in below code:

Tags: matplotlib, plot, python-3.7, valueerror

```
import numpy as np
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

#Class to calculate Camber and Thickness Distribution

class naca:                                                    # defining class naca
    def __init__(self,airfoil):
        self.airfoil = airfoil
        print ('NACA Airfoil is',airfoil ,'\n')
        self.__maxcamber=int(airfoil[0:1])/100 
        print ('Maximum Camber of airfoil as a %age of chord is' ,self.__maxcamber *100)
        self.__pos=int(airfoil[1:2])/10 
        print ('Position of maximum camber from leading edge as a %age of chord is' ,self.__pos*100)
        self.__thick=int(airfoil[2:4])/100 
        print ('Maximum Thickness of airfoil as a %age of chord is' ,self.__thick * 100 ,'\n')


    #Function to calculate Camber  
    def camber(self,x):                                        # defining camber function               
        if x < self.__pos and x>=0:
            z=(self.__maxcamber/(self.__pos**2))*((2*self.__pos*x)-x**2) 
            return z
        elif x>=self.__pos and x<=1:
            z=(self.__maxcamber/((1-self.__pos)**2))*(1-(2*self.__pos)+(2*self.__pos*x)-x**2)
            return z
        else:
            raise Exception ('Entered value of x/c should be between 0 to 1')
  
    #Function to calculate Thickness 
    def thickness (self,x):                                    # defining thickness function        
        if 0<=x<=1:
            t= 5*self.__thick*(0.2969*math.sqrt(x) - 0.1260*x - 0.3516*x**2 + 0.2843*x**3 - 0.1036*x**4)
            return t
        else:
            raise Exception ('Entered value of x/c should be between 0 to 1')
    
#Class to calculate x-derivative of Camber and Thickness distribution function 
class derivative(naca):                                        # parent class naca mentioned in the bracket
        def __init__(self,airfoil):
            super().__init__(airfoil)                          # calling the previous class attributes

        # Finding x-derivative of camber 
        def d_camber(self,xa):   
            h=0.01
            if xa==0:
                dx=(super().camber(xa+h)-super().camber(xa))/h         # forward differencing
                return dx
            elif xa==1:
                dx=(super().camber(xa)-super().camber(xa-h))/h         # backward differencing
                return dx
            else:
                dx=(super().camber(xa+h)-super().camber(xa-h))/(2*h)   # central differencing
                return dx

        # Finding x-derivative of thickness
        def d_thick(self,xa):  
            h=0.01
            if xa==0:
                dt=(super().thickness(xa+h)-super().thickness(xa))/h         # forward differencing
                return dt
            elif xa==1:
                dt=(super().thickness(xa)-super().thickness(xa-h))/h         # backward differencing
                return dt
            else:
                dt=(super().thickness(xa+h)-super().thickness(xa-h))/(2*h)   # central differencing
                return dt
                   
#Class to calculate flow around an arbitary airfoil using thin-airfoil theory
class thinairfoiltheory(derivative):    #parent class mentioned in the bracket
        def __init__(self, airfoil):
            super().__init__(airfoil)    #calling the previous class attributes   
        
        def sectional(self,alphad,f):
            n=15                             ### it is not taking value more than 15. n is actually related to the number of division used in intergration
                                             ##check how to give n=100.For n>15 it is giving error???
                #we have to increase thye value of n for accuracy
            alphar=alphad*(np.pi/180)
            thetal=0
            thetah=np.pi
            h=(np.pi-0)/n
            th=0
            sum1=0
            sum2=0
            sum3=0
            for i in range(1, n): #composite trapezoidal rule used for integration
                th=th+h
                x=0.5*(1-np.cos(th))
                sum1=sum1+super().d_camber(x)
                sum2=sum2+(super().d_camber(x)*np.cos(th))
                sum3=sum3+(super().d_camber(x)*np.cos(2*th))
                               
            xl=0.5*(1-np.cos(thetal))
            xh=0.5*(1-np.cos(thetah))
            
            finalsum1=(h/2)*(super().d_camber(xl)+super().d_camber(xh))+(h*sum1)
            a0=(1/np.pi)*finalsum1
            
            finalsum2=(h/2)*(((super().d_camber(xl))*np.cos(thetal))+((super().d_camber(xh))*np.cos(thetah)))+(h*sum2)
            a1=(2/np.pi)*finalsum2
            
            finalsum3=(h/2)*(((super().d_camber(xl))*np.cos(2*thetal))+((super().d_camber(xh))*np.cos(2*thetah)))+(h*sum3)
            a2=(2/np.pi)*finalsum3
            
            
            cl=2*(np.pi*(alphar-a0)+(np.pi/2)*a1)
            cmc=-(np.pi/4)*(a1-a2)
            
            #print("sectional lift coefficient", cl)
            #print("quatercord point moment",cmc)
            
            if f==1:
                return cl
            elif f==2:
                return cmc

        def plot(self,ff):
                     
            deg=np.linspace(0,30,50) 
            liftcoff=self.sectional(deg,1)
            momcoff=self.sectional(deg,2)
               
                               
            if ff==1:         #graph for lift coefficient
                plt.plot(deg,liftcoff)  
                plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = (10, 6)           #This fixes the size of plot displayed below
                plt.rcParams.update({'font.size': 15})            #This fixes the font size of parameters in the plot below
                plt.xlabel('Angle of attack in degress')        #This labels the x-axis
                plt.ylabel('Liff coeff')         #This labels the y-axis
                plt.grid(b=True, color='black', alpha=0.3,linewidth=1)
                
            elif ff==2:    #graph for moment coefficient
                ##the moment coeff graph is not plotting.I cannot figure out the problem???
                
                plt.plot(deg,momcoff)  
                plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = (10, 6)           #This fixes the size of plot displayed
                plt.rcParams.update({'font.size': 15})            #This fixes the font size of parameters
                plt.xlabel('Angle of attack in degress')        #This labels the x-axis
                plt.ylabel('mom coeff')         #This labels the y-axis
                plt.grid(b=True, color='black', alpha=0.3,linewidth=1)
```

Comment: a=thinairfoiltheory("3306")
  a.plot(2)
    
    4 frames
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/matplotlib/axes/_base.py in _plot_args(self, tup, kwargs)
        340 
        341         if x.shape[0] != y.shape[0]:
    --> 342             raise ValueError(f"x and y must have same first dimension, but "
        343                              f"have shapes {x.shape} and {y.shape}")
        344         if x.ndim > 2 or y.ndim > 2:
    
    ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (50,) and (1,)

Comment: Please add some explanation what the code is supposed to do and things you tried. Also, try to shorten the code to create a minimal demonstration of the problem. Please also add the sample code to call the functions. You can click "edit" to edit and change the contents of the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error is at this line of code `cmc=-(np.pi/4)*(a1-a2)`, for ff=2 your sectional() function will return **cmc**, which is a constant. I think your formula must be missing *alphar* to calculate the moment coefficient for different angles.

Comment: Thanks Sai. It was correct and solved my problem.